# Spring - use in injected request scope component in async call

Tags: spring

I have a rest service that need to do some operations in async mode.
The REST service do the operation on scope request component.

My question:
Do i allowed to use request scope component in an new thread (outside the original http request thread)?
What will happened to resources like entity manager that need to be created in the end of the scope , when spring will close them now? will it be at the end of the http request , so entity manager can be closed in the middle of the async call ?

What is the recipe for this scenario ? what should be the scope of PaymentService, so entity manager will be opened and closed around the async call ?
I can do it explicit , but i am looking for best practice in case exist.

```
public class RestPayment{
      @Autowired PaymentService paymentService;

      public void pay(){
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                     paymentService.charge(....);           
              }
               }).start();
      }
}

@Component
@Scope(value="request")
public class PaymentService{
        @Transactional(value="MainDB", propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
        public void charge(...){
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Spring is out of the picture the moment you call "new".  That object wasn't created by the bean factory, so it's not under Spring's control.  It won't inject those dependencies - it's all on you.

A much better solution would be to create an executor service pool that is under Spring's control.  Let it create the Runnable class that you want to execute.  That way it'll know to inject in the service that you need.

Comment: I assume you correct just like new thread in jee container, so what should be a recipe for async operation that is not done in http scope

Comment: These kinds of things would be better done using JMS or executor service.  The new concurrency package is far preferrable to you writing using raw Threads.

Comment: I am going to do the async call with executer service (new thread was just for the question ). however this not solve the problem on which scope should be the paymentservice